# Count without nested select: is this possible?

Tags: sql, count, sql-optimization

Database:

```
Department  Position             Points
    A        Manager               50
    A        Supervisor            10
    A        Supervisor            10
    A        Staff                 2
    A        Staff                 2
    B        Manager               40
    B        SuperVisor            8
    B        Staff                 2
    B        Staff                 2
    B        Staff                 2
```

Desired query result:

```
Dept  Manager Count  Supervisor Count  Staff Count    Staff Total Pts   

A        1                  2              2                 4
B        1                  1              3                 4
```

Is the desired query result possible without using nested select with count?

We have a certain stored procedure similar to this using nested counts and we like to make it simpler and perform better/faster

Comment: Also you can use PIVOT query for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to count only the specific data

```
Select Department,
       count(case when Position = 'Manager' then 1 END) as Manager,
       count(case when Position = 'Supervisor' then 1 END) as Supervisor,
       count(case when Position = 'Staff' then 1 END) as Staff
From yourtable
Group by Department
```

If you are using `Sql Server` use this

```
SELECT Department,
       Manager,
       Supervisor,
       Staff
FROM   Yourtable
       PIVOT (Count(Position)
             FOR Position IN (Manager,Supervisor,Staff))pv
```

Comment: Thanks. I added an additional question

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional `SUM`:

```
SELECT Department,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 'Manager' THEN 1 END) as Manager,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 'Supervisor' THEN 1 END) as Supervisor,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Position = 'Staff' THEN 1 END) as Staff
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Department
```

Comment: Thanks. I added an additional question

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use PIVOT operator:

```
select Detartment, Manager, Supervisor, Staff
from yourtable
pivot (count(Position) for Position in (Manager, Supervisor, Staff)) Result
```